# Does uniform boundedness mean having uniform distribution?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_i$,$i=1,2,.....n$ be a sequence of random variable. It is assumed that $X_i's$ are uniformly bounded. That is, 
$$P(|X_i|<M)=1$$.
Does it mean that $X_i$ follow uniform distribution in $(-M,M)$ ?

Comment: Hardly, what about $X_i := 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might follow a uniform distribution, but it might not. Consider for example a triangular pdf between $[-1,1]$, that is

$f_x(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{c} x+1,-1\leq x\leq0 \\ x-1,\quad 0\leq x\leq 1 \\ 0,\quad otherwise\end{array}\right. $.

For this pdf, the probability $P(|X|<1)=1$, however the distribution is not uniform.